# Append mustache templates in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mustache

I am trying to append the same mustache template several times but each time with different values that comes from php via ajax. The values are stored in an array.

Unfortunately each appended template includes the values from the last entry in the array.

If I add `alert("test");` at the end of the loop it is working. Do I have to wait until the append-function is finished? If so, how can I do that?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function postData() {
        var id = localStorage.getItem('user-id');
        var token = localStorage.getItem('user-token');
        var vars = "id=" + id + "&token=" + token;
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "../php/getUsers.php";

          hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);

                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                        var templateData = {
                            name: data[i].name,
                            id: data[i].id

                        };
                      var id=templateData['id'];

                      $.get('templates/user.htm', function(templates) {

                            var template = $(templates).filter('#user-template').html();
                            $('#user-container').append(Mustache.render(template, templateData));
                        });
                 //alert("Test"); 
                 }
            }
        }
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        hr.send(vars);
    });
```

Comment: lookup the fix for setTimeout in loops, same closure issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the callback function for the `$.get` call is invoked, `templateData` already changed in the next iterations of the `for` loop.

To avoid this common closure problem, you can do the following:

```
$.get('templates/user.htm', (function (templateData) {
    return function(templates) {
        var template = $(templates).filter('#user-template').html();
        $('#user-container').append(Mustache.render(template, templateData));
    }
})(templateData));
```

If you are using ES2015, you don't need to change the callback function, because you can use `let` instead of `var` to define the `templateData` variable:

```
let templateData = {
    name: data[i].name,
    id: data[i].id

};

...

$.get('templates/user.htm', function(templates) {
    var template = $(templates).filter('#user-template').html();
    $('#user-container').append(Mustache.render(template, templateData));
});
```

Comment: This (without ES2015) doesn't seem to work on mobile devices (tested on Arduino - Samsung Internet, Microsoft - Microsoft Edge). Do you have any idea why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is there a console where you can check for errors?

Comment: I realised it has nothing to do with my initial question. Console says: "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF" and highlights line `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {`I guess I should ask about this in a separate question

Comment: Try logging the value of hr.responseText: console.log(hr.responseText).

Comment: New question asked about this issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999866/ajax-script-only-working-in-firefox-not-working-in-chrome-safari-edge)