# Ajax script only working in Firefox (not working in Chrome, Safari, Edge,...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

this code is working fine in Firefox, but in all other browsers I have tested I get the error "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF" in line `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)`. The json-string looks like this:

```
[{"ID":"1","token":"1234","name":"Test Satio","matno":"11111","reg_date":"2017-10-24 00:00:00","last_active":"2017-10-24 00:00:00","user_id":"25"},{"ID":"3","token":"2232434","name":"Test Satio 2","matno":"44444","reg_date":"2017-10-23 00:00:00","last_active":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","user_id":"25"},{"ID":"5","token":"32233","name":"Test Satio 3","matno":"12","reg_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","last_active":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","user_id":"25"}]
```

JS-Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function postData() {
    var id = localStorage.getItem('user-id');
    var token = localStorage.getItem('user-token');
    var vars = "id=" + id + "&token=" + token;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "../php/getUsers.php";

      hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  //in this line I get the error
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                    var templateData = {
                        name: data[i].name,
                        id: data[i].id

                    };
                  var id=templateData['id'];

                  $.get('templates/user.htm', (function (templateData) {
                     return function(templates) {
                        var template = $(templates).filter('#user-template').html();
                        $('#user-container').append(Mustache.render(template,    templateData));
                      }
                  })(templateData));

             }
        }
    }
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    hr.send(vars);
});
```

What do I need to change to get this code working in all browsers?

Thanks, Lukas

Comment: Is `getUsers.php` setting the correct Content-Type header for JSON (`application/json`) before sending the response?

Comment: In php I create an array `$arr=[]` , fill it with content and with `echo json_encode($arr)` I send it back to JS

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't answer my question. ;-) Use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before echoing anything and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, I did it ;) Unfortunately the problem is still there.

Comment: This mix of jquery and oldschool ajax makes my eyes bleed a little.  Be aware that firing off a loop of `$.get` requests doesn’t mean that their success callbacks will be executed in that same order.

Comment: Your remarks helped me to find the problem: The values in localStorage have been wrong in the other browsers. @Connum thanks for the good advise to set the right content-type header. James: thanks, I realized that too. Next task is to improve the loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to fire off a request for the user template for each user, I think you can do it once and save it.

I've simplified your code a bit and changed your outer ajax to use jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function postData() {

    $.post({
      url: "../php/getUsers.php",
      data: {
        id: localStorage.getItem('user-id'),
        token: localStorage.getItem('user-token')
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
        // now get the template
        $.get('templates/user.htm', function (templates) {
          var template = $(templates).filter('#user-template').html();
          // we have the template and userdata array
          data.map(function (el) {
            return {id: el.id, name: el.name};
          }).forEach(function (templateData) {
             $('#user-container').append(Mustache.render(template, templateData));
          });
        });
      }
    });

});
```